# Issue with Maven Central behind proxy in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has no problem to use Maven Central when VPN is off and "No proxy" is selected.

When connected with VPN and using the company's proxy, Maven Central Archtype list is empty even if proxy test was successful.

idea.log shows the following messages:

```
2022-12-19 15:17:44,788 [77795073]   WARN - #o.j.i.maven - Using extension org.jetbrains.idea.maven.maven3.Maven3Support@febaa86 to start MavenServer
2022-12-19 15:17:45,070 [77795355]   INFO - #o.j.i.maven - Sent token to maven server
```

Anyone can help?

[image]
[image]

I even tried setting VM option in Build tool section (although I think it should be irrelavent) and it was to no avail.

[image]

[image]

Full log:

```
2022-12-20 08:54:25,159 [     19]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------
2022-12-20 08:54:25,389 [    249]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\Documents\plugins\Groovy, version=223.7571.182, package=org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy, isBundled=true) misses optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml
2022-12-20 08:54:25,389 [    249]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\Documents\plugins\Groovy, version=223.7571.182, package=org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy, isBundled=true) misses optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml
2022-12-20 08:54:25,606 [    466]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 380 ms
2022-12-20 08:54:25,619 [    479]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-223.7571.182, 29 Nov 2022 10:36)
2022-12-20 08:54:25,620 [    480]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64)
2022-12-20 08:54:25,624 [    484]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - JRE: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
2022-12-20 08:54:25,624 [    484]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - JVM: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
2022-12-20 08:54:25,634 [    494]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - PID: 14532
2022-12-20 08:54:25,734 [    594]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\Documents\plugins\Kotlin, version=223-1.7.20-release-201-IJ7571.182, package=org.jetbrains.kotlin, isBundled=true) misses optional descriptor performance-plugin.xml
2022-12-20 08:54:25,762 [    622]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - JVM options: [exit, -Xms128m, -Xmx750m, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50, -XX:CICompilerCount=2, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions, -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot,trieDescend, -ea, -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false, -Dsun.java2d.metal=true, -Djbr.catch.SIGABRT=true, -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="", -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true, -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true, -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off, -Xmx2048m, -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\\JetBrains\\IdeaIC2022.3\idea64.exe.vmoptions, -Djava.system.class.loader=com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader, -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains, -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2022.3, -Djna.boot.library.path=C:\Users\abc\Documents/lib/jna/amd64, -Dpty4j.preferred.native.folder=C:\Users\abc\Documents/lib/pty4j, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djna.nounpack=true, -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea, -Dsplash=true, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.dnd.peer=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.windows=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.java2d=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi=ALL-UNNAMED, -Dide.native.launcher=true, -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\abc\\java_error_in_idea64_%p.log, -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\abc\\java_error_in_idea64.hprof]
2022-12-20 08:54:25,763 [    623]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - args: 
2022-12-20 08:54:25,764 [    624]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - library path: C:\Users\abc\Documents\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\windows\CCM\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\bin\x32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\bin\x64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_20.2.4\bin;C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_20.2.2\bin;C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\bin;;C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\abc\Documents\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin;;.
2022-12-20 08:54:25,765 [    625]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - boot library path: C:\Users\abc\Documents\jbr\bin
2022-12-20 08:54:25,824 [    684]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - locale=en_CA JNU=Cp1252 file.encoding=Cp1252
  idea.config.path=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.3
  idea.system.path=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.3
  idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.3\plugins
  idea.log.path=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.3\log
2022-12-20 08:54:25,834 [    694]   INFO - #c.i.i.AppStarter - CPU cores: 4; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@6da75138[Running, parallelism = 3, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@1260f2bf
2022-12-20 08:54:26,054 [    914]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Module intellij.sh.python is not enabled because dependency com.intellij.modules.python is not available
Module intellij.space.gateway is not enabled because dependency com.jetbrains.gateway is not available
Module intellij.space.php is not enabled because dependency com.jetbrains.php is not available
Module intellij.space.index is not enabled because dependency intellij.indexing.shared is not available
2022-12-20 08:54:26,501 [   1361]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Eclipse Keymap (223.7571.182), NetBeans Keymap (223.7571.182), Shell Script (223.7571.182), Mercurial (223.7571.182), Copyright (223.7571.182), Smali Support (223.7571.182), IntelliLang (223.7571.182), Gradle (223.7571.182), Markdown (223.7571.182), com.intellij.dev (223.7571.182), XSLT Debugger (223.7571.182), XPathView + XSLT (223.7571.182), Subversion (223.7571.182), Gradle DSL API (223.7571.182), Android Design Tools (223.7571.182), Machine Learning in Search Everywhere (223.7571.182), YAML (223.7571.182), Package Search (223.7571.182), JetBrains Marketplace Licensing Support (223.7571.182), Code With Me (223.7571.182), JavaFX (223.7571.182), GitHub (223.7571.182), Bytecode Viewer (223.7571.182), JetBrains Repository Search (223.7571.182), Grazie (223.7571.182), Visual Studio Keymap (223.7571.182), Ant (223.7571.182), IDEA CORE (223.7571.182), Projector Libraries for Code With Me and Remote Development (223.7571.182), Gradle-Maven (223.7571.182), Plugin DevKit (223.7571.182), Java IDE Customization (223.7571.182), Configuration Script (223.7571.182), Toml (223.7571.182), Java Internationalization (223.7571.182), Machine Learning Code Completion (223.7571.182), Java Bytecode Decompiler (223.7571.182), Properties (223.7571.182), Git (223.7571.182), Kotlin (223-1.7.20-release-201-IJ7571.182), WebP Support (223.7571.182), Groovy (223.7571.182), Maven (223.7571.182), Eclipse Interoperability (223.7571.182), Task Management (223.7571.182), TextMate Bundles (223.7571.182), Android (2022.1.1 Beta 2.223.7571.182), Java (223.7571.182), Space (223.7571.182), Gradle-Java (223.7571.182), UI Designer (223.7571.182), Java Stream Debugger (223.7571.182), Lombok (223.7571.182), Maven server api classes (223.7571.182), Qodana (223.7571.182), Terminal (223.7571.182), Shared Indexes (223.7571.182), Settings Sync (223.7571.182), Code Coverage for Java (223.7571.182), JUnit (223.7571.182), JetBrains maven model api classes (223.7571.182), Gradle Dependency Updater Implementation (223.7571.182), EditorConfig (223.7571.182), IDE Features Trainer (223.7571.182), Perforce Helix Core (223.7571.182), Windows 10 Light Theme (223.7571.182), com.intellij.tracing.ide (223.7571.182), Images (223.7571.182), TestNG (223.7571.182)
2022-12-20 08:54:27,454 [   2314]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Loaded path macros: {MAVEN_REPOSITORY=C:\Users\abc\.m2\repository}
2022-12-20 08:54:27,455 [   2315]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSConnector - VFS uses strict names enumerator
2022-12-20 08:54:27,776 [   2636]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSConnector - VFS uses regular attributes storage
2022-12-20 08:54:28,059 [   2919]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.FSRecords - using REGULAR storage for VFS records
2022-12-20 08:54:28,389 [   3249]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSConnector - 310 ms to load free records and inverted name index
2022-12-20 08:54:28,613 [   3473]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.serverflags.ServerFlagInitializer - Enabled server flags: 
2022-12-20 08:54:28,637 [   3497]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.ExpiredPluginsState - Plugins to skip: []
2022-12-20 08:54:28,756 [   3616]   INFO - #c.i.u.n.s.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized
2022-12-20 08:54:29,023 [   3883]   INFO - #o.j.i.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342
2022-12-20 08:54:29,424 [   4284]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.i.l.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Users\abc\Documents\bin\fsnotifier.exe
2022-12-20 08:54:29,713 [   4573]   WARN - #c.i.u.s.SvgCacheManager - Icon cache will be recreated or previous version of data reused, (db=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.3\icons-v6.db)
2022-12-20 08:54:31,180 [   6040]   INFO - #c.i.i.s.p.i.SharedIndexMainZipStorage - Shared Indexes Storage is opened and empty
2022-12-20 08:54:31,216 [   6076]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.i.l.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational.
2022-12-20 08:54:31,467 [   6327]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.i.w.WslFileWatcher - WSL file watcher: C:\Users\abc\Documents\bin\fsnotifier-wsl
2022-12-20 08:54:33,902 [   8762]   INFO - #c.i.o.u.i.UpdateCheckerService - channel: release
2022-12-20 08:54:37,038 [  11898]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.FileBasedIndexImpl - Indices to be built:FilenameIndex(v = 258)
2022-12-20 08:54:37,067 [  11927]   INFO - c.i.u.i.FileBasedIndexDataInitialization - Index data initialization done: 7459 ms. Initialized indexes: [FilenameIndex, TodoIndex, FrameworkDetectionIndex, filetypes, IdIndex, Trigram.Index, fileIncludes, DomFileIndex, RelaxSymbolIndex, Stubs, XmlTagNames, XmlNamespaces, SchemaTypeInheritance, html5.custom.attributes.index, yaml.keys.name, json.file.root.values, editorconfig.index.name, xmlProperties, XsltSymbolIndex, java.auto.module.name, bytecodeAnalysis, java.source.module.name, java.null.method.argument, java.fun.expression, java.binary.plus.expression, IdeaPluginRegistrationIndex, PluginIdDependenciesIndex, PluginIdModuleIndex, devkit.ExtensionPointClassIndex, devkit.ExtensionPointIndex, LombokConfigIndex, JavaFxControllerClassIndex, ant-imports, javafx.id.name, javafx.custom.component, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinJvmMetadataVersionIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinJsMetadataVersionIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinPartialPackageNamesIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinClassFileIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinJavaScriptMetaFileIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinMetadataFileIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinMetadataFilePackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinModuleMappingIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinJvmModuleAnnotationsIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinBuiltInsMetadataIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinPackageSourcesMemberNamesIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinStdlibIndex, com.intellij.uiDesigner.FormClassIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KlibMetaFileIndex, BindingXmlIndex, com.android.tools.idea.model.AndroidManifestIndex$Companion$NAME$1.NAME, NavXmlIndex].
2022-12-20 08:54:39,305 [  14165]   INFO - c.i.p.s.StubIndexImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Index data initialization done: 2237 ms. Initialized stub indexes: {gr.annot.members, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyContractedFunctionShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinSuperClassIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFullClassNameIndex, dom.namespaceKey, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyNothingPropertyShortNameIndex, markdown.header.anchor, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinScriptFqnIndex, java.anonymous.baseref, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinInnerTypeAliasClassIdIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinJvmNameAnnotationIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinOverridableInternalMembersShortNameIndex, java.class.extlist, gr.script.fqn, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeFqNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelFunctionByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinClassShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinMultifileClassPartIndex, markdown.header, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTypeAliasByExpansionShortNameIndex, gr.class.super, java.field.name, java.class.fqn, jvm.static.member.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFilePartClassIndex, java.module.name, gr.annot.method.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyNothingFunctionShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeClassByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelPropertyByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinAnnotationsIndex, gr.anonymous.class, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelFunctionFqnNameIndex, dom.elementClass, gr.class.fqn, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFunctionShortNameIndex, kotlin.primeIndexKey, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinExactPackagesIndex, gr.script.class, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelExtensionsByReceiverTypeIndex, gr.field.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelPropertyFqnNameIndex, java.method.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelTypeAliasByPackageIndex, java.class.shortname, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTypeAliasShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinExtensionsInObjectsByReceiverTypeIndex, gr.method.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinSubclassObjectNameIndex, properties.index, java.annotations, jvm.static.member.type, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelClassByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinPropertyShortNameIndex, java.method.parameter.types, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelTypeAliasFqNameIndex}.
2022-12-20 08:55:03,873 [  38733]   INFO - #c.j.r.f.FollowMeManager - Register new user 0:'abc' with ClientId=ClientId(value=Host)
2022-12-20 08:55:05,229 [  40089]   INFO - #c.i.o.a.Experiments - Experimental features enabled for user: wsl.p9.support, wsl.prefer.p9.support, wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser, wsl.execute.with.wsl.exe, linux.native.menu, recent.and.edited.files.together, show.create.new.element.in.popup, search.everywhere.mixed.results, new.project.wizard, editor.reader.mode, new.large.text.file.viewer, terminal.shell.command.handling
2022-12-20 08:55:13,036 [  47896]   WARN - #o.j.i.maven - Using extension org.jetbrains.idea.maven.maven3.Maven3Support@7f50729b to start MavenServer
2022-12-20 08:55:13,547 [  48407]   INFO - #o.j.i.maven - Sent token to maven server
```

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: the log messages after I select "Maven Central" from Catalog are:

2022-12-19 15:17:44,788 [77795073]   WARN - #o.j.i.maven - Using extension org.jetbrains.idea.maven.maven3.Maven3Support@febaa86 to start MavenServer
2022-12-19 15:17:45,070 [77795355]   INFO - #o.j.i.maven - Sent token to maven server

Comment: Is it possible to share full idea.log after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: Full log has been posted. Thanks

Comment: There is similar case on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273968/Cannot-connect-to-the-Maven-process. Please follow it for updates.